# How to pad a number with leading zeros in the middle of a string?

Tags: python, list

An example of the list would be this:

```
   Name
   KOI-234
   KOI-123
   KOI-3004
   KOI-21
   KOI-4325
```

and I simply want to make all these numbers to have at least 4 characters, so it would look like this:

```
   Name
   KOI-0234
   KOI-0123
   KOI-3004
   KOI-0021
   KOI-4325
```

I've already tried this code, but I guess it reads the 'KOI' part as not number and doesn't add the zeros.

```
first_list = db['Name']
second_list = []
for pl in first_list:
    second_list.append(pl.zfill(4))
```

So, how can I achieve that?

Comment: It does add the zeroes; at the start of the string, where the docs say it will. If that's not where you want them, you'll have to specify that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [format specifications](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec):

```
lst = ['KOI-234', 'KOI-123', 'KOI-3004', 'KOI-21', 'KOI-4325']

['{}-{:0>4}'.format(*i.split('-')) for i in lst]
# ['KOI-0234', 'KOI-0123', 'KOI-3004', 'KOI-0021', 'KOI-4325']
```

If you want to remove leading zeros:

```
[f'{i}-{int(j)}' for i, j in map(lambda x: x.split('-'), lst)]
```

Comment: Thank you! And, by using this method, would you show me how to remove the leading zeros as well? So that now I'd have 'KOI-0001' turned to 'KOI-1'.

Comment: @AugustoBaldo You are welcome! See my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

It does not add zeroes because every element/name already has more than 4 symbols.
You can try using regular expressions:

```
import re

my_list = ['KOI-123', 'KOI-3004', 'KOI-21']
pattern = r'(?<=-)\w+'  # regex to capture the part of the string after the hyphen

for pl in my_list: 
     match_after_dash = re.search(pattern, pl)    # find the matching object after the hyphen
     pl = 'KOI-' + match_after_dash.group(0).zfill(4)    # concatenate the first (fixed?) part of  string with the numbers part
     print(pl)  # print out the resulting value of a list element
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `str.split`:

```
n, *d = ['Name', 'KOI-234', 'KOI-123', 'KOI-3004', 'KOI-21', 'KOI-4325']
result = [n, *[f'{a}-{b.zfill(4)}' for a, b in map(lambda x:x.split('-'), d)]]
```

Output:

```
['Name', 'KOI-0234', 'KOI-0123', 'KOI-3004', 'KOI-0021', 'KOI-4325']
```

And if you want to compute the offset value generically:

```
n, *d = ['Name', 'KOI-234', 'KOI-123', 'KOI-3004', 'KOI-21', 'KOI-4325']
_d = [i.split('-') for i in d]
offset = max(map(len, [b for _, b in _d]))
result = [n, *[f'{a}-{b.zfill(offset)}' for a, b in _d]]
```

Output:

```
['Name', 'KOI-0234', 'KOI-0123', 'KOI-3004', 'KOI-0021', 'KOI-4325']
```